# Override javascript parameters on a protected page with Greasemonkey?

Tags: printing, parameters, overriding, greasemonkey

I'm trying to enable printing on a page which has disabled printing (and downloading). The code below is made with *Flip PDF Professional*.

At the bottom of the javascript below, I would like to change

`bookConfig.enablePrint="No";` and `bookConfig.enableDownload="No";`

to `bookConfig.enablePrint="Yes";` and `bookConfig.enableDownload="Yes";`

Any idea?

```
<script language="javascript">  
    var aliasConfig = {
    ... ...
    }
    var bookConfig = {
    ... ...
    }
    bookConfig.bookTitle="www.FlipBuilder.com";

    ...
    bookConfig.enablePrint="Yes";
    bookConfig.enableDownload="Yes";
    bookConfig.enableFlipSound="Enable";
    ...
</script>
```